# CSS, GRID, trying keep grid size 3x3 while overflow scrolling the extra

Tags: css, grid

I want the grid to be no bigger than 3X3 and then scroll the rest.... Looks great for 9 boxes and less lol!!

This is the look I like but I'm only deriving with 9 boxes or less:
[Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQpl0.png)

However anything other than 9 gives me this:
[not wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRtmS.png)

column-count: 3:
[not wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEWiD.png)

```
.container{
    height: 70vh;
    width: 80vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.box{
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <title>Routing️</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        {% for i in range(num) %}
        <div class = "box">hi</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Objective: Only show the 3X3 and scroll the rest (at the same size).
Please help me fix my overflow /not overflowing problem lol.

Comment: `column-count: 3;` ? Please provide HTML.

Comment: Put the HTML in there. Sorry. Should have specified im trying to seperate the boxes as divs.

Column-count was a good idea; however, it was a little off centered and scrolled right instead of down.

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the boxes > 9 in the container? Could you just alter the code to put them afterwards, scrolling 'normally'?

Comment: I put the picture of column-count up there so you can see because I probably described it weird lol.

Comment: @ Haworth. YES! That is the look I am going for! I cant seem to get it to scroll though. I remember there being a CSS grid attribute for that but I can't find it on my notes.

Comment: I'm looking it up now. I think i'm thinking of grid-auto-rows/colums and grid-auto flow. Playing with the lesson. I'll keep you updated lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
Works perfectly!
Webkit toolbar is to make the scrollbar display none. It is for Chrome. Love the look of the scrollbar being hidden.

I was able to specify height with minmax and grid-auto-rows did the trick for the implicity added rows.

Thanks for all your help!

Posted updated code and picture:

```
.container{
    height: 70vh;
    width: 80vw;
    background-color: rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.2);
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid: repeat(3, minmax(150px,200px)) / repeat(3, minmax(150px,200px));
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px,150px);
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
} 

.box{
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

[Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x35G4.png)
[On Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAJer.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your code. you used -webkit-scrollbar and made the container display none. So, The scroll bar is not showing.
Another thing is though you used grid layout you must add height to you box or all the boxs will shrink when there is more boxs. So, need to add height to box.
You can try this code below. Which is perfectly working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <title>Routing️</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
      <div class = "box">hi</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    height: 70vh;
    width: 80vw;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(3, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr);
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}



.box{
    height: 300px;
    margin: 2%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}
```